# Anonymous VPS Permitting Exit Nodes?

Tags: exit-relays, vps

I want to run some exit nodes to give back to the community. Are there any lists of VPS providers in U.S. or Europe who allow anonymous VPS purchase, preferably through cryptocurrency, who also allow exit nodes?

Since exit nodes seem to be the scarcest resource on the network, I would expect to find enthusiastic support for people asking how to set up exit nodes anonymously.

Comment: You may want to think about whether you rally want to use a VPS. Tor, when you are an exit nods will require quite some resources. So you might want to use dedicated hardware instead. Also, depending on the provider and the virtualization infrastructure used you might quickly run into artificial limits, like number of open connections/file descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good list of the information you are looking for: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/GoodBadISPs